Bootstrap Utility Conflict with Tailwind
[Problem]
I'm using tailwind as my main style library in my react front-end project
meanwhile, I'm also using react-boostrap component such as { Modal, Form },
so I had to using on of the bootstrap library to config the component style,
unfortunately, there are conflicts on classNames such as "padding" between tailwind and bootstrap utility.
How do I prevent bootstrap utility applying to components other than its react-bootstrap component?
[Approach Tried]

some solutions indicates using normal bootstrap component instead of react-bootstrap => gotta replace all the components in the existing project(really messy)
using tailwind pre-fix
disable conflicting bootstrap className in bootstrap config


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
